# Which query is optimized?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am fetching a list of products including their prices. I want to get just enable prices.

I wrote two type of queries:

```
context.Products.Include("Prices").Where(p=>p.Prices.Where(pr=>pr.Enable==true).Count()>0).ToList();
```

And the other one is:

```
context.Products.Include("Prices").ToList().RemoveAll(p => p.Prices.Where(pr => pr.Enable == true).ToList().Count == 0);
```

Which one is more optimized?

Comment: What does your profiler tell you?

Comment: In general, doing more on the database side is faster especially if you have the right indexes.

Comment: Did you mean, "how do I measure which one is faster?"

Comment: it also depends on the size of the `Products`, it should be done on server side (the first query). Even the first query is not optimized, you should use `Any` instead of `Where` and `Count` like this: `context.Products.Include("Prices").Where(p=>p.Prices.Any(pr=>pr.Enable)).ToList();`

Comment: @Hopeless Yes you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using an `EntityFramework` context, the first one is way better.

This is because `Linq to SQL` will translate the statement into an `SQL` statement. The `Where` statements will result in an according `SQL` `Where`. So only the necessary subset of the elements are retrieved.

The second statement retrieves all Products and Prices and then removes the unwanted elements.

This assumes that you have a remote database. If your database is running locally or you already have all Products and Prices in memory its not so easy to tell (you would have to use the profiler for that).

Comment: Thanks in advanced. And the how can I use sql profiler in sql server 2008 R2?

Comment: You should use the C# profiler in Visual Studio. The second query just selects all elements.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of question really depends on a lot of things, so it is not so easy to say which is better.

But from the code, the first one is doing the where clause at **sql** side, where the second code is getting all the data out from sql and do the where in **application**.

so it will depend on the sql server, the application hardware and data amount.